# Angular Js stateProvider .state url not load for appending urls

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using `$stateProvider` for URL routing.

I'm using the below code.

```
$stateProvider
      .state('myapp', {
        url:'/myapp',
        templateUrl: 'views/dashboard/main.html',
        resolve: {
            loadMyDirectives:function($ocLazyLoad){
                console.log($ocLazyLoad);
                return $ocLazyLoad.load(
                {
                    name:'NewApp',
                    files:[
                      'modules/directives/header/header.js',
                      'modules/directives/sidebar/sidebar.js',                     
                    ]
                })


    })
```

If the url is " http://localhost:8080/#/myapp " means the header and sidebar js will be loaded. If I did not refresh the page means it's working fine with url appending. But, if I refreshed with url appending like http://localhost:8080/#/myapp/orders/list the js files were not loading.

Please help to resolve the issue.